# Prove that enough points in the plane guarantee there is a convex hexagon

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, ramsey-theory

> Prove that if we draw enough points in the plane (no collinear
> triplets), then there will be six such points that form a convex
> hexagon.

I tried to draw points in a plane sheet, trying to avoid the formation of the convex hexagon, but I can't do that, I just don't understand why. I think that with 8 points there is already necessarily a convex hexagon. There is no way to avoid, I guess (but I may be wrong!).

Comment: $8$ is not enough. Take the vertices of a "square in a square". To avoid $3$ collinear points you have to shift one of the squares a bit, so they do not have the same "center".

Comment: Where did you get this problem?

Comment: @Robert Israel: https://problemas-de-matematica.fandom.com/pt/wiki/Problemas_de_teoria_de_Ramsey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a special case of a result due to Erdos-Szekeres. They have proven  the following theorem:
For any integer, $n\geq 3$ there exists a positive integer $r(n)$ such that any set of at least $r(n)$ points in general position in the plane, i.e. no three of them are on a line, contains $n$ points that are the vertices of a convex $n$-gon.

The proof of Erdos and Szekeres is based on the Ramsey Theory and you can bound from above the number $r(n)$ by some Ramsey number. If you want a references here

https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2000-37-04/S0273-0979-00-00877-6/S0273-0979-00-00877-6.pdf